# Try...catch stopping the app (Dart/Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, try-catch, handle

I‘m trying handle exception in main class with try...catch. But after exception my app is stopped and continue to work after 1 minute. This problem only on Android. iOS version works correctly. What should I do to fix this?

```
bool exception = false;

var myCSV = CSV.from(
    url:
    'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/deniro.csv', 
    delimiter: ";",
    title: true);

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  facultyValue = pref.getString("facultyValue");
  groupValue = pref.getString("groupValue");

  try {
    await myCSV.initFinished;
  } catch (e) {exception = true;}

  print(myCSV.rowsCount);

  if(exception == false) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myCSV.rowsCount - 1; i++) {
      groupe.add(myCSV[i][0]);
      day.add(myCSV[i][1]);
      number.add(myCSV[i][2]);
    }
    SharedPreferences preff = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    preff.setStringList("groupe", groupe);
    preff.setStringList("day", day);
    preff.setStringList("number", number);
  } else {
    SharedPreferences preff = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    groupe = preff.getStringList("groupe") ?? [];
    day = preff.getStringList("day") ?? [];
    number = preff.getStringList("number") ?? [];
  }

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: are you sure its from `try-catch` and not the `await` inside it?

Comment: I'm a little worried about the line `catch (e) {exception = true;}` because previously there are no 'exception' variables and in case the try clause fails, it goes to the catch clause and there it finds a variable that you haven't created and fails an application. Try creating `bool exception` before the try and see if that helps.

Comment: I have variable bool exception = false;. And in this line (await myCSV.initFinished;) I wait information from Internet, and if everything is ok, my variable is false, else it true, than massive, which parse saved information, is started (if exception is false).

Comment: What is `myCSV.initFinished;`? If exception is caught then this line might create issue: `print(myCSV.rowsCount);`

Comment: I updated code. Check, please. Everything work correctly if there is internet connection. If internet connection is poor, application stop on `await myCSV.initFinished;` and continues to run after 1 minute.